# Tensorflow: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to build a neural network model with one hidden layer (1024 nodes). The hidden layer is nothing but a relu unit. I am also processing the input data in batches of 128.

The inputs are images of size 28 * 28. In the following code I get the error in line

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
Error: TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_64:0", shape=(128, 784), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Here is the code I have written

```py
#Initialize

batch_size = 128

layer1_input = 28 * 28
hidden_layer1 = 1024
num_labels = 10
num_steps = 3001

#Create neural network model
def create_model(inp, w, b):
    layer1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(inp, w['w1']), b['b1'])
    layer1 = tf.nn.relu(layer1)
    layer2 = tf.matmul(layer1, w['w2']) + b['b2']
    return layer2

#Initialize variables
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, layer1_input))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))

w = {
'w1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_input, hidden_layer1])),
'w2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_layer1, num_labels]))
}
b = {
'b1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer1])),
'b2': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))
}

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model)

tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

model = create_model(x, w, b)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(model, y))    
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

#Process
with tf.Session(graph=graph1) as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    total_batch = int(train_dataset.shape[0] / batch_size)

    for epoch in range(num_steps):    
        loss = 0
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = train_dataset[epoch * batch_size:(epoch+1) * batch_size, :], train_labels[epoch * batch_size:(epoch+1) * batch_size,:]

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            loss = loss + c
        loss = loss / total_batch
        if epoch % 500 == 0:
            print ("Epoch :", epoch, ". cost = {:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
            valid_prediction = tf.run(tf_valid_dataset, {x: tf_valid_dataset})
            print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
    test_prediction = tf.run(tf_test_dataset,  {x: tf_test_dataset})
    print("TEST accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Comment: Where is graph1 defined? I don't see it in your code!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Variable **x** is not in the same graph as **model**, try to define all of these in the same graph scope. For example,

```py
# define a graph
graph1 = tf.Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    # placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(...)
    y = tf.placeholder(...)
    # create model
    model = create(x, w, b)

with tf.Session(graph=graph1) as sess:
# initialize all the variables
sess.run(init)
# then feed_dict
# ......
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the changes you mentioned. However I am not getting the following error `Fetch argument 0 has invalid type <type 'int'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a int into a Tensor or Operation.)` in the same line `sess.run(.., feed_dict=...)` . Here is the code http://pastebin.com/raw/iGZjgEi9

Comment: I just checked the loss is an int, instead it should be a Tensor. Will try fixing that. :)

Answer (score 69):

This worked for me

```
from keras import backend as K
```

and after predicting my data i inserted this part of code
then i had again loaded the model.

```
K.clear_session()
```

i faced this problem in production server,
but in my pc it was running fine

...........

```
from keras import backend as K

#Before prediction
K.clear_session()

#After prediction
K.clear_session()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem related to question

Comment: we can never find direct answers for the question .Even i had the same misconception but while finding the answer i found it on git where my problem was completely diffrent from that given solution.

Comment: It helped me solve this problem, seems pretty much related to the problem ;)

Comment: Got a legacy project and got this problem then solved with this solution. You're my life saver

Comment: @yunus I tried your way but its giving me the following error:
"AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'"

Comment: A small code snipet could be useful to diagnose ur use case . because this has worked for others.

Answer (score 15):

If you use django server, just runserver with `--nothreading`
for example:

```
python manage.py runserver --nothreading
```

Comment: This worked for meas I develop locally, but will everything be okay on a production server?

Comment: This works and is great for development and testing. To answer to above comment, I would just outright discourage mapping tensorflow sessions and running predictions inside HTTP requests.

Comment: @MattCremeens No you shouldn't disable threading on production. It would cripple your web server.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with flask. adding `--without-threads` flag to `flask run` or `threaded=False` to `app.run()` fixed it

Comment: I'd like to use them with a threaded flask server. Should I initialize the model in a thread and run inference in another ?

Comment: @iratzhash I think you need to ask another question for that. I'm not familiar with threading on python and how can you achieve thread-safety with tensorflow

Comment: @iratzhash hey did you get to the bottom of this? what are you using for multithreaded flask with tensorflow 1? Tensorflow serving?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using loop while calling in CNN multiple times, I fixed my problem by doing the following:

```
# Declare this as global:

global graph

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# Then just before you call in your model, use this

with graph.as_default():

# call you models here
```

Note: In my case too, the app ran fine for the first time and then gave the error above. Using the above fix solved the problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When posting code sections, use appropriate formatting via the { } in the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

The error message `TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("...", dtype=dtype) is not an element of this graph` can also arise in case you run a session outside of the scope of its `with` statement. Consider:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(logits, feed_dict=feed_dict) 

sess.run(logits, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

If `logits` and `feed_dict` are defined properly, the first `sess.run` command will execute normally, but the second will raise the mentioned error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also experience this while working on notebooks hosted on online learning platforms like Coursera. So, implementing following code could help get over with the issue.

Implement this at the topmost block of Notebook file:

1. from keras import backend as K
2. K.clear_session()

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @javan-peymanfard and @hmadali-shafiee, I ran into this issue when loading the model in an API.  I was using FastAPI with uvicorn.  To fix the issue I just set the API function definitions to `async` similar to this:

```
@app.post('/endpoint_name')
async def endpoint_function():
    # Do stuff here, including possibly (re)loading the model
```