# How to use TensorFlow with Flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, deep-learning

I am building a multi threaded rest api with using flask, tensorflow and keras models. After getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785224/tensorflow-cannot-interpret-feed-dict-key-as-tensor) error, I did some research and came up with the following solution:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

@app.route('/createLearningTask', methods=['POST'])
def createLearningTask():
    request_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    executor.submit(LearningTask().processData)
    return ('', 200)
```

Basically, I submit each new post request to executor. And in each request, I build model with given parameters, producing model, predict and store result for another GET request.

```
class LearningTask:

    resultDict = {} # access to this map is protected by locks, which I omitted in here

    def processData(self, **kwargs):
        graph = tf.Graph() # tf = tensorflow
        with graph.as_default():
            with tf.Session().as_default():
                model = Sequential() # keras model
                model.add(..)
                model.add(..)
                model.add(..)
                model.compile(..)
                model.fit(..)
                model.predict(..)
```

I omitted irrelevant parts of the code. It works good, after processing data and getting results, I save it to dictionary. I create new graph and new session for each post request.

After reading [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8538) and [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397) github discussions, I produced my solution.

***My question is, is that solution safe and correct usage of tensorflow? In [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph), it says graph is not thread safe, but I did some load test and it can handle simultaneous requests with no problem.***

Comment: You are asking two different questions. I think. One is about the Web concurrent architecture. Why do you need `tf.Graph()` when you are using Keras ? Isn't Keras [thread-safe](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6124) ?  if you are worried about queueing in TF consider the thread-safe queues like PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (regardless to tensorflow) this is bad practice. What will happen if more than 10 requests were executed before the .process() stmt finished? When all 10 executors are occupied

What happens if the worker suddenly dies? The tasks are lost

A better model would be a persistant task queue, each request would be added to the queue, and executed when a worker process is avaliable

Celery might do the trick for you

Comment: I am developing on Windows machine and tried Celery. Unfortunately, it won't work with windows, but I definitely use it in future with linux environment. My main concern, does this usage cause problems tensorflow sessions? For example, does it cause data loss or data interference between two different sessions and threads in this usage?(assume low load and no worker dies suddenly)

Comment: I don't know TF, but I can suggest few things that can make your life easy. You can use docker for running linux python containers on windows machine. If performance is an issue, you can read about python GIL - that might convience you moving to a single threaded model, which can assure no data / lock / loss / session issues