# Tensorflow: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to write linear regression code using Tensorflow. But I am getting an error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor
> Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element
> of this graph.
```

Maybe I am messing something up with the `tf.Graph()` but I tried to remove those part and try to rerun but getting same error.

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = np.random.randn(2000, 3)
w_real = [0.3, 0.5, 0.1]
b_real = -0.2
noise = np.random.randn(1,2000)*0.1
y_data = np.matmul(w_real, x_data.T) + b_real + noise

NUM_STEPS = 100
g = tf.Graph()

wb = []

with g.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,3])
    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None)

    with tf.name_scope('inference') as scope:
        w = tf.Variable([[0,0,0]], dtype=tf.float32,name='weights')
        b = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32, name='bias')
        y_pred = tf.matmul(w,tf.transpose(x)) + b

    with tf.name_scope('loss_function') as scope:
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred))

    with tf.name_scope('train') as scope:
        learning_rate = 0.5
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(NUM_STEPS):
        sess.run(train, {x:x_data, y_true:y_data})
        if step%10 == 0:
            print(step, sess.run([w,b]))
        wb.append(sess.run([w,b]))

    print("Final Weights: ", wb)
```

I have already looked at [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785224/tensorflow-cannot-interpret-feed-dict-key-as-tensor) but getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each session is associated with a graph, and the session you are creating in:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

Is for the default graph, not for `g`. To fix it, you can simply do:

```
with g.as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
```

Note this is also a problem with the definition of `init`, which will be an initializer for the variables in the default graph - which is empty. Do instead:

```
with g.as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the problem was with `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()`.